How can I use lifetime annotations to avoid these clone()?
I'm working on a clone of Flappy Bird.
I'm using Macroquad.rs and Bevy ECS.
However, I've been using a lot of cloning operations when handling textures for the bird and barriers.
I tried simply adding lifetime annotations to the components, but the compiler complains that it requires a 'static lifetime.
What should I do?
Here’s some relevant code. The entire project can be found here.
Minimal Reproducible Example Here:
use macroquad::prelude::{Texture2D, BLACK, draw_texture, load_texture, next_frame};
use bevy_ecs::prelude::*;
use macroquad::color::{PURPLE, WHITE};
use macroquad::window::clear_background;

#[derive(Component, Debug)]
pub struct TextureRender {
    pub texture: Texture2D,
}

pub fn texture_render(mut commands: Commands, query: Query<(Entity, &TextureRender)>) {
    for (entity, texture) in &query {
        draw_texture(&texture.texture, 100., 100., WHITE);
        commands.entity(entity).despawn();
    }
}

#[macroquad::main("Flappy Bird")]
async fn main() {
    let mut world = World::new();
    let bird_img = load_texture("bird.png").await.unwrap();
    let mut schedule = Schedule::default();
    schedule.add_systems(texture_render);
    loop {
        clear_background(PURPLE);
        world.spawn((TextureRender { texture: bird_img.clone() },)).id();
        schedule.run(&mut world);
        next_frame().await;
    }
}

I have tired to simply add lifetime annotations to my component, but the compiler complains that he wants 'static.
How can I do to avoid these clone?

Please include a Minimal Reproducible Example embedded in the question, not as a link. In particular, few snippets from your project are not a MRE - they are neither reproducible nor minimal. And your whole project may be reproducible, but it's definitely not minimal.

Lifetimes likely won't help avoid clones since Bevy components need to be 'static. You could use Arcs for shared ownership (so the .clone()s are cheap) but my intuition is that there's a better way to do this via resources or asset handles.

But when I render a texture, I just want an immutable reference. Why can't it be copied freely?

Texture2D is an enum that stores either an Arc or an identifier, so cloning it is very cheap

@Codebling that won't work, because the call to spawn requires Component + 'static And you can't construct something that meets that, from a non-constant reference. Why is the clone a problem?

The Texture2D is an immutable reference. Whats wrong with just rendering it?
